# delete then insert in a transaction deadlock on innodb

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

my table scheme just like below

```
CREATE TABLE `mapping` (
   `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `id1` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
   `id2` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id1`, `id2`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

and i start a transaction, then get a error:

```
begin transaction
delete from mapping where id1=xxx and id2 IN (...)
insert into mapping (id1,id2) values(?,?),(?,?)...
end
Lock wait timeout exceeded;try restarting transaction.
```

it seems if the operation in delete&insert have a same record, innodb will have row-lock deadlock, what's the elegant way to do in this situation

Comment: i just simplify the question, i actually delete and insert a different  record set, it may have intersection

Comment: Even with your update to the question it's still not clear why you want to delete rows first

Comment: delete&insert will have a same id1 in one transaction, i wanna delete all relation for id1, and then insert new relationship...